# Why are some of my command line arguments being ignored?

Tags: python, scripting, command-line

I am trying to render an [animation](https://free3d.com/3d-model/gear-animation-80073.html) of gears. In the GUI I have set the options shown in the picture below and when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> the animation renders and saves each frame as a '.jpg' file to the `/tmp/` directory.

[image]

However, when I try running from the command line using

```
blender.exe -b .\gear_colored_last.blend -f 1 --render-format PNG --render-output //render_ --debug-all
```

I get the following output:

[image]

As you can see, it tries to save '.jpg' files under `/tmp/`. The only argument it took was the frame number `-f`. All other arguments were ignored in favour of those saved in the GUI. How do I overwrite the GUI settings from the command line?

I am using Windows 10 and blender 2.83.

Comment: "always position -f or -a as the last argument" https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/render.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender doesn't get to read any of the arguments after `-f 1`, as per the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/render.html):

> **Note**
>
> Arguments are executed in the order they are given!
>
> The following command will not work, since the output and extension are set after Blender is told to render:
> `blender -b file.blend -a -x 1 -o //render`
>
> The following command will behave as expected:
> `blender -b file.blend -x 1 -o //render -a`
>
> Always position `-f` or `-a` as the last arguments.

Comment: Thank you! I feel a bit silly because I read that page multiple times to understand all the options available but for some reason didn't see the note that answered my question.